# Separate values in a list to make coordinate pair

Tags: python, list, csv

Below is my current code.

```
import csv
def function():

    latitude = []
    longitude = []
    with open('data.csv', 'rU') as input: #
          dL= list(csv.reader(input))
          sL = [row[4] for row in dL[1:]]
          longitude.append(sL)
          sL1 = [row[3] for row in dL[1:]]
          latitude.append(sL1)

    print latitude
    print longitude

    print
    for i in range(0, len(latitude)):
        print "Co-ordinates (" + str(latitude[i]) + "," + str(longitude[i]) + ")"

function()
```

Right so my output produces this

```
[['-20.71', '-20.73', '-20.88', '-20.78', '-20.76', '-20.68', '-20.95', '-21.06', '-21.05', '-20.9']]
[['116.77', '116.75', '116.67', '117.15', '117.16', '117.19', '117.37', '117.44', '116.26', '117.64']]

Co-ordinates (['-20.71', '-20.73', '-20.88', '-20.78', '-20.76', '-20.68', '-20.95', '-21.06', '-21.05', '-20.9'],['116.77', '116.75', '116.67', '117.15', '117.16', '117.19', '117.37', '117.44', '116.26', '117.64'])
```

This shows the lists that I want to produce.

What i want to do is produce an output that looks like this

```
Co-ordinates (-20.71,116.77)
Co-ordinates (-20.73, 116.75)
```

and so on for all the coordinate pairs.

Is there any way to get the output for coordinates I have to the output that I want?

Answer (score 2):

1. you want to use `extend` instead of `append`.
2. `zip(latitude, longitude)`

In second thought, you can just do `longitude = [row[4] for row in dL[1:]]`. you don't need to extend (or append, or initialize) anything.

better:

```
with open('data.csv', 'rU') as infile:
      dl = list(csv.reader(infile))
lat_long = [tuple(row[3:5]) for row in dl[1:]]
for (lat, lng) in lat_long:
    print "Co-ordinates ({0}, {1})".format(lat, lng)
```

Comment: Thanks @Elazar the code worked perfect for what I needed however I did not need to zip latitude and longitude but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid pre-building the list and the list-comps you're performing by using the following:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import imap, islice

with open('data.csv', 'rU') as fin:
    dL= csv.reader(fin)
    for lat, lon in imap(itemgetter(3, 4), islice(dL, 1, None)):
        print 'coordinates ({}, {})'.format(lat, lon)
```

Comment: I prefer to use `next(dL, None)  # skip headers` over `islice()`; it's a little more self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
for lat, lng in zip(latitude, longitude):
    print "Co-ordinates (%s, %s)" % (lat, lng)
```

This will work after you transform `latitude` and `longitude` into "flat" lists instead of lists containing one list. See Elazar's hint about using `extend`.

Comment: I didn't see your answer, but used the same names, so it looks as if I copied it :-/ . And: I don't think it is recommended to use the `%` operator.